Writing SQL functions in R
I am using R and SQL together. I have this table in a DB2 server - I made a simpler version locally in R:
library(sqldf)

mytable <- data.frame(
    name = c("Alice", "Alice", "Alice",      # Alice appears in all years
             "Bob", "Bob",                    # Bob appears in 2009-2010
             "Charlie", "Charlie",            # Charlie appears in 2010-2011
             "David", "David",                # David appears in 2009,2011
             "Eve"),                          # Eve appears in just 2009
    year = c(2009, 2010, 2011,               # Years for Alice
             2009, 2010,                      # Years for Bob
             2010, 2011,                      # Years for Charlie
             2009, 2011,                      # Years for David
             2009)                           # Year for Eve
)

I am trying to find out the following:
how many names in uniquely: (2009), (2010), (2011), (2009, 2010), (2009, 2011), (2010, 2011), (2009, 2010, 2011)?
I first made a list of the min-max year combinations:
year_range_query <- sqldf("
    SELECT MIN(year) as min_year, MAX(year) as max_year 
    FROM mytable")

min_year <- year_range_query$min_year
max_year <- year_range_query$max_year
years <- min_year:max_year
results <- data.frame()

Now, I am trying to write an R function which communicates with the SQL server and the local R environment:
for(r in 1:length(years)) {
    combinations <- combn(years, r)
    
    for(i in 1:ncol(combinations)) {
        years_in_combo <- combinations[,i]
        
        query <- sprintf("
            SELECT '%s' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
            FROM (
                SELECT name
                FROM mytable
                WHERE year IN (%s)
                GROUP BY name
                HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = %d
            )
        ",
        paste(years_in_combo, collapse="-"),
        paste(years_in_combo, collapse=","),
        length(years_in_combo)
        )
        
        result <- sqldf(query)
        results <- rbind(results, result)
    }
}

The code ran, but when looking at the results, I can see that there duplicates (e.g. 2009-2010 appears multiple times):
          years matching_names
1       2009-2010              2
2       2009-2011              2
3       2010-2011              2
4  2009-2010-2011              1
5       2009-2010              2
6       2009-2011              2
7       2010-2011              2
8  2009-2010-2011              1
9            2009              4
10           2010              3
11           2011              3
12      2009-2010              2
13      2009-2011              2
14      2010-2011              2
15 2009-2010-2011              1
16      2009-2010              2
17      2009-2011              2
18      2010-2011              2
19 2009-2010-2011              1
20      2009-2010              2
21      2009-2011              2
22      2010-2011              2
23 2009-2010-2011              1
24           2009              4
25           2010              3
26           2011              3
27      2009-2010              2
28      2009-2011              2
29      2010-2011              2
30 2009-2010-2011              1

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? For the final answer, if I sum the counts column, it should match the count(*) for the original table. Note that I would like to do this without GROUP_CONCAT since I might need to use this code later on a different server which does not support GROUP_CONCAT.

Idea 1: I wanted to avoid this, but I suppose I could pre-craft all queries and then launch them:
    # manually determine the years
    years <- c(2009, 2010, 2011)
    
    generate_year_indicators <- function(years) {
        indicators <- sapply(years, function(y) {
            sprintf("MAX(CASE WHEN year = %d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_%d", y, y)
        })
        paste(indicators, collapse = ",\n        ")
    }
    
    generate_combination_condition <- function(combo_years, all_years) {
        conditions <- sapply(all_years, function(y) {
            if(y %in% combo_years) {
                sprintf("has_%d = 1", y)
            } else {
                sprintf("has_%d = 0", y)
            }
        })
        paste(conditions, collapse = " AND ")
    }
    
    all_combinations <- list()
    for(r in 1:length(years)) {
        combos <- combn(years, r)
        for(i in 1:ncol(combos)) {
            all_combinations[[length(all_combinations) + 1]] <- combos[,i]
        }
    }
    
    base_query <- sprintf("
        SELECT 
            name,
            %s
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY name
    ", generate_year_indicators(years))
    
    year_indicators <- sqldf(base_query)
    
    results <- data.frame(year_combination = character(0), count = numeric(0))
    
    for(combo in all_combinations) {
        combo_name <- paste(combo, collapse="_")
        count_query <- sprintf("
            SELECT '%s' as year_combination,
                   SUM(CASE WHEN %s THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as count
            FROM year_indicators
        ", combo_name, generate_combination_condition(combo, years))
        combo_result <- sqldf(count_query)
        results <- rbind(results, combo_result)
    }
    
    results <- results[order(nchar(results$year_combination), 
                             results$year_combination), ]
    rownames(results) <- NULL
    
    print(results)

  year_combination count
1             2009     1
2             2010     0
3             2011     0
4        2009_2010     1
5        2009_2011     1
6        2010_2011     1
7   2009_2010_2011     1


Idea 2: Perhaps I could just get R to generate the text for the full SQL query and then manually copy/paste this into the SQL IDE?
    generate_full_sql_query <- function(years) {
        # First, let's create the year indicator columns
        year_indicators <- sapply(years, function(y) {
            sprintf("MAX(CASE WHEN year = %d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_%d", y, y)
        })
        year_indicators_text <- paste(year_indicators, collapse = ",\n    ")
        
        # Generate all possible year combinations
        all_combinations <- list()
        for(r in 1:length(years)) {
            combos <- combn(years, r)
            for(i in 1:ncol(combos)) {
                all_combinations[[length(all_combinations) + 1]] <- combos[,i]
            }
        }
        
        # Create the WITH clause for the base query
        base_cte <- sprintf("WITH year_indicators AS (\n  SELECT \n    name,\n    %s\n  FROM mytable\n  GROUP BY name\n)", 
                            year_indicators_text)
        
        # Create UNION ALL queries for each combination
        combination_queries <- sapply(all_combinations, function(combo) {
            combo_name <- paste(combo, collapse="_")
            conditions <- sapply(years, function(y) {
                if(y %in% combo) {
                    sprintf("has_%d = 1", y)
                } else {
                    sprintf("has_%d = 0", y)
                }
            })
            condition_text <- paste(conditions, collapse = " AND ")
            
            sprintf("  SELECT\n    '%s' as year_combination,\n    COUNT(*) as count\n  FROM year_indicators\n  WHERE %s",
                    combo_name, condition_text)
        })
        
        # Combine everything into the final query
        final_query <- paste(
            base_cte,
            "SELECT * FROM (",
            paste(combination_queries, collapse = "\n  UNION ALL\n"),
            ") results",
            "ORDER BY LENGTH(year_combination), year_combination;",
            sep = "\n"
        )
        
        return(final_query)
    }
    
    years <- c(2009, 2010, 2011)
    cat(generate_full_sql_query(years))

output
   WITH year_indicators AS (
     SELECT 
       name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2009 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_2009,
       MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2010 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_2010,
       MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2011 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_2011
     FROM mytable
     GROUP BY name
   )
   SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT
       '2009' as year_combination,
       COUNT(*) as count
     FROM year_indicators
     WHERE has_2009 = 1 AND has_2010 = 0 AND has_2011 = 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       '2010' as year_combination,
       COUNT(*) as count
     FROM year_indicators
     WHERE has_2009 = 0 AND has_2010 = 1 AND has_2011 = 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       '2011' as year_combination,
       COUNT(*) as count
     FROM year_indicators
     WHERE has_2009 = 0 AND has_2010 = 0 AND has_2011 = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       '2009_2010' as year_combination,
       COUNT(*) as count
     FROM year_indicators
     WHERE has_2009 = 1 AND has_2010 = 1 AND has_2011 = 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       '2009_2011' as year_combination,
       COUNT(*) as count
     FROM year_indicators
     WHERE has_2009 = 1 AND has_2010 = 0 AND has_2011 = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       '2010_2011' as year_combination,
       COUNT(*) as count
     FROM year_indicators
     WHERE has_2009 = 0 AND has_2010 = 1 AND has_2011 = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       '2009_2010_2011' as year_combination,
       COUNT(*) as count
     FROM year_indicators
     WHERE has_2009 = 1 AND has_2010 = 1 AND has_2011 = 1
   ) results
   ORDER BY LENGTH(year_combination), year_combination;


I am under the impression that sqldf was written to run locally, not to connect to external servers.
You may want to look at RODBC.
WARNING: incomplete code below!
library( RODBC )
dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect( sConnectionString, rows_at_time = 10000, readOnlyOptimize = TRUE )
dfResults <- sqlQuery( dbhandle, sSqlQuery )

thanks for the feedback michael ... see idea2... I think this might be a good idea?

Simply, move the nested sqldf and rbind() to the inner loop. Even better, don't run rbind inside a loop to avoid the quadratic copy. See Patrick Burn's R Inferno - Circle 2: Growing Objects (PDF).
Since combn supports a function argument, incorporate your query run directly with simplify=FALSE:
query_run <- function(y) {        
  query <- sprintf(
    "
      SELECT '%s' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
      FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        WHERE year IN (%s)
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = %d
      )
    ",
    paste(y, collapse="-"),
    paste(y, collapse=","),
    length(y)
  )
       
  cat(query)
  result <- sqldf(query)
  results <- rbind(results, result)
}

combinations <- lapply(
  seq_along(years), \(r) combn(years, r, query_run, simplify = FALSE)
)

cat Output
      SELECT '2009' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
      FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        WHERE year IN (2009)
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 1
      )
    
      SELECT '2010' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
      FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        WHERE year IN (2010)
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 1
      )
    
      SELECT '2011' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
      FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        WHERE year IN (2011)
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 1
      )
    
      SELECT '2009-2010' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
      FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        WHERE year IN (2009,2010)
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 2
      )
    
      SELECT '2009-2011' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
      FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        WHERE year IN (2009,2011)
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 2
      )
    
      SELECT '2010-2011' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
      FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        WHERE year IN (2010,2011)
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 2
      )
    
      SELECT '2009-2010-2011' as years, COUNT(*) as matching_names
      FROM (
        SELECT name
        FROM mytable
        WHERE year IN (2009,2010,2011)
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 3
      )


thank you! I think your idea is similar to what I did in idea2?

Idea 2 is a single query build but my answer is to address your first attempt. If you need to transpose final data, then yes run that conditional aggregate query. You can have the query_run in this solution return an SQL string instead that you paste together with UNION for final query.

1) To avoid using group_concat we encode each year as a bit in an integer so that 1 represents the first element in years (where years is defined in question), 2 represents the second element, 4 represents the third and in general the ith element is represented by 2^(i-1).  Subsets of years can be represented by adding the years together. For example to represent years[1] and years[3] use 2^(1-1) + 2^(3-1) = 1 + 4 = 5.
Going the other way bin2year takes an integer vector x of such encoded subsets and the years vector and returns a character vector of the years in each element of x separated by dashes so for example
bin2year(5, 2009:2011)  # 5 means years[1] and years[3]
## [1] "2009-2011"

combos contains the possible combinations (i.e. subsets) of years in the binary form just discussed.  We then perform the computation in SQL and using the result from SQL in R we decode the result back using bin2year and sort.  With this setup group_concat corresponds to using plain sum on the encoded values.
Below we used power(2, x) to take powers of 2. This is equivalent to bit shifting of 1 so alternately power(2, x) could be replaced with (1 << x) .
Note that the fn$ in fn$sqldf causes any expression within backquotes in the SQL string to be evaluated in R and then substituted into the SQL statement at that point.  fn$ comes from the gsubfn package which the sqldf package loads.  It works with just about any function.  It is not specific to sqldf.  An alternative would be to use sprintf .
# this code uses mytable and years from the question

library(magrittr)
library(sqldf)
   
bin2year <- function(x, years) {
  m <- sapply(x, \(z) as.integer(intToBits(z)))
  m <- diag(years) %*% m[seq_along(years), ]
  ch <- apply(m, 2, function(x) paste(x[x > 0], collapse = "-"))
  ch[ch != ""]
}

combos <- data.frame(year = seq_len(2^length(years)-1))

res <- fn$sqldf("with tmp as (
    select name, sum(power(2, year - `min(years)`)) year
    from mytable 
    group by name
  )
  select year, count(b.year) n
  from combos a left join tmp b using (year)
  group by year")

res %>%
  within(year <- bin2year(year, years)) %>%
  .[order(lengths(strsplit(.$year, "-"))), ]

giving
            year n
1           2009 1
2           2010 0
4           2011 0
3      2009-2010 1
5      2009-2011 1
6      2010-2011 1
7 2009-2010-2011 1

2) Firstly, using the R vector years defined in the question create the combotab data.frame and using mytable create the ag data.frame.  The latter could be created in SQL using group_concat (as commented out below) but we have done it in R instead since the question asked not to use it. (Note that your database may have string_agg which is the similar to group_concat in which case you could use the commented out code instead after modifying it to use string_agg.)
Then we can do the rest in SQL using combotab and mytable.
combotab <- c(years, NA, NA) %>%
  combn(3) %>%
  t %>%
  unique %>%
  apply(1, \(x) as.numeric(na.omit(x))) %>%
  .[order(lengths(.))] %>%   
  sapply(paste, collapse = "-") %>%
  data.frame(years = .)

# ag <- sqldf(
#  "select name, group_concat(cast(year as int), '-') years
#   from mytable
#   group by name")

ag <- aggregate(list(years = mytable$year), mytable["name"],
  paste, collapse = "-")

sqldf("select y.years, count(a.name) n from combotab y
  left join ag a using (years)
  group by y.years")

giving
           years n
1           2009 1
2           2010 0
3           2011 0
4      2009-2010 1
5      2009-2011 1
6      2010-2011 1
7 2009-2010-2011 1


thank you so much for your answer! Do you think idea#2 that I included in my question is correct?

I get an error when I try to run it but without getting into the details the approach of generating an SQL seems ok in principle.  Note that MAX(CASE WHEN year = 2009 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as has_2009 is the same as MAX(year = 2009) has_2009 at least for SQLite.
